# Typescript definition for Websocket client side in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

EDIT2: I just tested it and the problem doesnt occur if the project is created with the newest version of angular (1.0.0-rc.1)

Im using Visual Studio code with angular cli and currently im creating a service for WebSocket communication.
I cant make the error

```
Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
```

go away.

Are there any typing packages for the WebSocket implementation of browsers? I can only find typings for the server.

EDIT:
My tsconfig.app.json (autogenerated by cli in the tsconfig inside of the src folder)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json (root, autogenerated by cli too)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any type. It's bundled with TypeScript. What does your tsconfig.json file contain?

Comment: The WebSocket type is declared in es2016. I just created a band new ng-cli project, and using WebSocket in its app.component.ts file compiles without any problem. What exactly are you doing? Is it an error emitted by VSCode, or an error emitted by ng build?

Comment: ng build is happy, in vscode every occurence of "WebSocket" is underlined in red. Everything works but vscode cant find the typings

Comment: tried it myself and you are right, one possible solution is just creating the project with the current cli. Thank you!